# Python list identifying duplicat pairs

Tags: python, list, traversal, forward

I have a list like below
[3, 5, 6, 8, 1, 5, 3, 9, 0, 8, 6]
I want to find out how many pairs in a list iterating in forward and reverse directions
I want the output like the following statement
2 pairs: (3,5) and (6,8)
Please help when you get a chance
I have tried something like as below but it is wrong so please help!

```
list2=[3, 5, 6, 8, 1, 5, 3, 9, 0, 8, 6]
list3=[]
for x in list2:
    if list2.count(x)>1:
        list3.append(x)
print ('dups is ',list3)
```

Thanks

Comment: Hello Lara. What exactly are you having trouble with? Do you know how to iterate in pairs? Are you having trouble applying that to iterating backwards? How about keeping track of the pairs?

Comment: The question is not clear. Could you explain a bit regarding pairs in forward and reverse direction? Do you want to count duplicated pairs too?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? Please put in some effort solving the problem yourself before asking here.

Comment: Hi juanpa.arrivillaga
   In the list if we traverse forward 3 and 5 are repeated while traversing backwards 6 and 8 so that is what is required to print. It may be an easy thing but since I am new to python having bit of trouble

Comment: @Lara - one way to do this is to build a dictionary/ hashmap for number and index, then find all those numbers that distance is 1 - group them, if those numbers appear twice, of course.

Comment: Thanks Daniel but how to do that

Answer (score 1):

You could use Counter from collection and feed it tuples where elements are in ascending order (to ignore actual order):

```
L = [3, 5, 6, 8, 1, 5, 3, 9, 0, 8, 6]

from collections import Counter

D = [pair for pair,count in
     Counter(map(tuple,map(sorted,zip(L,L[1:])))).items() 
     if count > 1]

print(D) # [(3, 5), (6, 8)]
```

How it works:

- `zip(L,L[1:])` pairs up every element with its successor

  (3, 5), (5, 6), (6, 8), (8, 1), (1, 5), (5, 3), (3, 9), (9, 0), (0, 8), (8, 6)

  but in there (3,5) and (5,3) are not the same
- `map(sorted,...)` sorts each of these pairs

  [3, 5], [5, 6], [6, 8], [1, 8], [1, 5], [3, 5], [3, 9], [0, 9], [0, 8], [6, 8]

  now both (5,3) and (3,5) becomes [3,5] and we have two matching [3,5]
  but those are small lists which are not hashable so they cannot be counted by Counter.
- `map(tuple,...)` turns the lists back into tuples  (which are hashable)

  (3, 5), (5, 6), (6, 8), (1, 8), (1, 5), (3, 5), (3, 9), (0, 9), (0, 8), (6, 8)
- `Counter(...)` computes a count of each pair (ordered tuples)
- The rest is a list comprehension that runs through the items of the Counter dictionary and picks the keys (pairs) that have a count greater than one.

Comment: Thanks Alain for your reply